# Nested dropdown menu in Bootstrap in mobile

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, nested

I'm building [this](http://kmaxat.com/mobilemap/index.html) website using bootstrap.

The problem is that i have nested drop downs. The dropdowns look nice and not cluttered in desktop version.

[image: Nested Dropdowns in the Desktop version]

However this is how it looks in mobile:

[image: Nested Dropdowns in the Mobile version]

They look cluttered, and you can't fold/unfold the deepest level of dropdowns. It just doesn't allow this.

I'm thinking there are better ways to represent information in mobile view. My approach was when person touches 'buildings/land' tab, i replace bottom navbar with contents of Buildings/Land, thus reducing one level of dropdowns.

Question: 
I'm really not experienced in developing UI. Is my approach sufficient?
**How should i solve this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a sweet JS plugin that plays nicely with Bootstrap, called [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/).  If you've ever used the Facebook iOS app, you'll be familiar with this layout.  There are some great [demos here.](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Snap.js/demo/apps/default.html)